# How to solve Application pools recycle when memory limits are exceeded Health check issue

Tags: 2013, health-analyzer

How to solve below health check rule in SharePoint 2013.

Application pools recycle when memory limits are exceeded.

i checked all application pools Recycling settings in affected servers there is no memory-based maximums set for application pools.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can stop recycling application pool. Follow these steps:

1. Go to **Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager** > **Application Pools**
2. Select your Application Pool > Right Click > **Recycling**

[image]

3. ***Uncheck* Specific Time(s) checkbox.**

[image]

4. Finish the steps.

Comment: if i do un check there is no issues to production sites? and is this best practice to do in sharepoint web application apppools?